# Return the key name and value found in a dictionary given a tuple of names

Tags: python

I have a tuple with some names I want to match against one or more dictionaries.

```
t = ('A', 'B')
d1 = {'A': 'foo', 'C': 'bar'}
d2 = {'A': 'foo', 'B': 'foobar', 'C': 'bar'}

def f(dict):
    """
    Given t a tuple of names, find which name exist in the input
    dictionary dict, and return the name found and its value.
    If all names in the input tuple are found, pick the first one
    in the tuple instead.
    """
    keys = set(dict)
    matches = keys.intersection(t)
    if len(matches) == 2:
        name = t[0]
    else:
        name = matches.pop()
    value = dict[name]
    return name, value


print f(d1)
print f(d2)
```

The output is `(A, foo)` in both cases.

This is not a lot of code, but it involves converting to a set, and then do an intersection. I was looking into some functools and haven't found anything useful.

Is there a more optimized way doing this using the standard library or built-in functions that I am not aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: is it always true that len(t) == 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for k in t:
    try:
        return k, dic[k]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

If you (like me) don't like exceptions, and assuming `None` is not a legitimate value:

```
for k in t:
    res = dic.get(k)
    if res is not None:
        return k, res
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain why this variant is optimal, as @CppLearner ask to. Take a look at my example. I think that exception is a lot more slow than an if statement. I know this code is quite short, but it doesn't seem to be optimal....

Comment: This is the simplest, and most readable of the current solutions and does not place limits on the number of items in the tuple.

Comment: I understand that, but he isn't asking for a more readable solution, he asked for an optimal solution... I don't know exactly how exceptions works on python, but i don't think they are faster than a simple if statement. And about placing limits on the number of items in the tuple, in the original code appeared this line: `if len(matches) == 2:`. Maybe len(t) == 2 is always true in his requirements...

Comment: It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness Than Permission.  In python, try/except is very efficient in the success case (which should be most of time). Aside from that, optimizing Python at the expense of readability is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(d):
  try:
    return next((x, d[x]) for x in t if x in d)
  except StopIteration:
    return ()
```

Comment: See [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-January/085247.html) comment about StopIteration. (If you know better, I will be happy to know)

Comment: @Elazar: That post is about raising the exception within the genex itself; my answer handles the exception normally generated by `next()` externally.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(d):
    """
    Given t a tuple of names, find which name exist in the input
    dictionary d, and return the name found and its value.
    If all names in the input tuple are found, pick the first one
    in the tuple instead.
    """
    for item in ((k, d[k]) for k in t if k in d):
        return item
    return ()
```

Comment: Just a thought: We've suggested here 3 different Ways To Do It, and you can come up with a couple of similar ways. How should I choose?

Answer (score -1):

The "try-except" variants are ok, but i don't think they are optimal for your case. If you know that t has only 2 values (i.e: len(t) == 2 is invariant/is always True), you can get advantage of this and try something like this:

```
def f(t, dic):
    if t[0] in dic:
        return t[0], dic[t[0]]
    elif t[1] in dic:
        return t[1], dic[t[1]]
    else: # Maybe any of t values are in dict
        return None, None
```

Comment: I would like to know why did you downvote me? Is there something i missunderstand?

Comment: I didn't, but you are doing at least two dictionary lookups in the best case. `x = dic.get(t[0]); if x is not None: return t[0], x` will be faster.